# ASP.NET MVC, IE 11, $(document).ready and back navigation caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

IE 11 has a feature that appears to be breaking my code called [Back navigation caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Of course my code works just fine in Google Chrome.

I have an MVC app and a simple script to load a partial page to fill in a div. This is in my HomeController class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // load the stats partial view
        $('#stats_div').load('/Home/Stats');
    });
```

When my page first loads, or whenever I refresh the page, my code is called and my div is filled in with my partial page properly.

In another part of my page, I have a few links that look something like this:

```
<li><a href="/Home/SelectVersion?version=1.0">1.0</a></li>
```

These links aren't doing much of anything right now except redirecting to the Index action of my HomeController like this:

```
public ActionResult SelectVersion(string version)
{
    // do some stuff

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Whenever those links are clicked, the browser reloads the page. But in IE11, my $(document).ready script is not called.

Again, this works just fine in Chrome.

What I'm after is that I need to reload the stats partial page when one of the SelectVersion links is pressed.

Am I missing something obvious? Am I doing this wrong? Or is IE11 just messing with me.

As recommended in the Back navigation caching link above, I have tried the following to try and prevent this behavior.

I added a `window.onbeforeunload` event with no effect:

```
// does not help
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
}
```

I added code to this function and it is being called each time.

I also tried loading the data in window.onpageshow and it behaved the same as $(document).ready:

```
// behaves the same as $(document).ready
window.onpageshow = function (e) {
    // load the stats partial view
    $('#stats_div').load('/Home/Stats');
}
```

In other words, I cannot get this to work. Has anyone else?

**Example Code**

Here's how to reproduce this with Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.1 and IE 11.

Create a new MVC application, all the defaults, nothing special.

Replace the contents of Index.cshtml with this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SelectVersion", new { version = "All" })">All Versions</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SelectVersion", new { version = "1.0" })">1.0</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SelectVersion", new { version = "2.0" })">2.0</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SelectVersion", new { version = "3.0" })">3.0</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="stats_div">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Overview</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Choose a Version...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <!--Script to render the charts-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // this function is called when the page is loaded and it is safe to access elements with jQuery
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // load the stats partial view
            $('#stats_div').load('/Home/Stats');
        });

    </script>
}
```

Modify HomeController.cs to have these methods:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult Stats()
    {
        ViewBag.VersionName = Session["VersionName"] ?? "Click on a Version";
        return PartialView("_Stats");
    }

    public ActionResult SelectVersion(string version)
    {
        Session["VersionName"] = version;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Add a file called _Stats.cshtml in the Views/Home folder with this content:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Overview</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Version
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @ViewBag.VersionName
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you run this in Chrome, every time you click on one of the version links, the panel at the right is updated.

When you run this in IE 11, the panel is not updated. After clicking on a version link you must manually refresh the page to get the panel to update.

This illustrates my problem.

Comment: Is no one else having this problem that I can easily reproduce with the example I provided?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you read your link.  A simple solution would be to define an onbeforepageunload event that does nothing.  Not an ideal solution, but seems like it would verify that this is the cause of the problem, and a workaround until you can find something else.

Alternatively, you could also define a pageshow event, and call load in that that instead.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried to do those things as you suggest with no luck. It's likely that I didn't implement it correctly as I'm a bit new at this. Do you have a code snippet that actually works? Thanks!

Comment: I added more details. I've tried what is mention in the link and in your answer and it does not help.

Comment: @KeithMurray - if it's not working, then your problem may not be related to this, but something else entirely.

Comment: any recommendations then? As I said it works great in Chrome and I don't think I'm doing anything out of the ordinary. Is there more information I could provide?

Comment: @KeithMurray - "Works in chrome" doesn't mean anything.  As an example, different browsers treat invalid code differently.  One browser make allow invalid code to work, while another doesn't.  I'm not saying that's the case here, i'm just saying that just because it works in another browser doesn't mean the fault is automatically with the browser it doesn't work on.  Can you create a repeatable small example of the problem?

Comment: I understand, but it means 'something' when it actually works properly in another browser. :) I will try and isolate a small example with a clean ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: @KeithMurray - Your problem has nothing to do with MVC, so you don't have to make it an MVC project, it can just be HTML

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39760/discussion-between-keith-murray-and-mystere-man)

Comment: @KeithMurray Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem... :(. My angular app is preloading some divs with past authenticated info. I've tried onpagehide, onbeforeunload, salting my sourcefiles names but nothing worked...

Comment: @Cyberdelphos Sort of. The only good solution I found was to flag my page as non-chacheable. In ASP.NET MVC I do this with the System.Web.Mvc.OutputCache attribute.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of weeks sitting on this one, I finally got a workaround (inspired by a redirect to some other page if the client is IE11).

```
if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
    window.onload = function () {
        if (!window.location.hash) {
            window.location = window.location + '#ie-workaround';
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);                        
        }
    }

}
```

Not the best solution but since this is highly specific to IE11, then we ought to apply a fix that is specific to that browser.